# How to get the stackTrace from an exception without printStackTrace?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is it possible to get the whole trace from an exception without using `printStackTrace()`?. 
One of the reasons it's because I use `CheckStyle` and I'm getting an ugly message. It's not enough just to call `toString()`. I want to get the complete message, because I needed to send me by email.

Currently, I'm doing

```
 StringWriter e = new StringWriter();
 exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(e));
```

--Avoid tracing with `printStackTrace()`, use log4j instead.

Otherwise, I could disable `CheckStyle` there.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html...

Comment: Further to @OliCharlesworth, [getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace())

Comment: Guess what log4j is going to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get error details try `Apache Commons Lang api`

There is a class [ExceptionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html) . You can use [getFullStackTrace](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getFullStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?:

```
Throwable thr = e.getStackTrace();
StackTraceElement[] lines = thr.getStackTrace();
```

And working from there. Also, take a look at the [javadocs Oli linked above](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

Comment: I couldn't get the causes. I finally used ExceptionUtils.

Comment: There is a .getCause() method under throwable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the stack trace from the current thread,
check this :

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will be able to print stack trace with no check style error.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;

String errorMessage = ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(exception);  
logger.debug(errorMessage);
```